# What is my last working day if my one month's notice falls on a Sunday?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I handed in my notice on the 15th of November. I'm required to give my employer one month's notice. From my understanding this would make my last day the 15th of December which happens to be a Sunday. I don't work weekends (it's not part of my contract).

Is my last working day Friday the 13th or Monday the 16th? I'm in the UK.

Comment: Why one day of work is so important that it seems to be a "thing" for you?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul The reason I am asking here is because my employer may come back and incorrectly say that the 16th is my last working. I'd rather not have to work the 16th if I'm not contractually obliged to. Cheers

Comment: @SouravGhosh Because it will determine when I can start working at my next job. It may also allow me to have some time off between starting my next job. But really, I just don't want to work an additional day at my current workplace if I don't have to.

Comment: Are you sure it's not simply 28 days, rather than a calendar month? I've never come across a place doing calendar months (after all, what if you gave your notice in in February, in which case you've only 28 days, unless it's a leap year?).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Notice period is calculated in calendar days (not working days) so the weekend is included, the notice period [begins the day **after** you give notice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/work/leaving-a-job/resigning/your-notice-period-when-resigning/) (not the same day) so if you gave notice on the 15th of then the first day of your notice period is actually the **16th** making the last day of your notice period the 15th of December i.e. your last day of *employment* would be the Sunday but your last day in the office would be the Friday. In practice this makes no difference unless your new job was starting over the weekend.

It's always a bit weird when it's done in months rather than weeks (given months are different lengths). With that in mind it's worth asking the question of "what's my last day?", you can even ask it as a bit of a cheeky leading question if you like "I assume the Friday the 13th is my last day in the office?" just to clear it up since regardless of the specified notice period if you and the company mutually agree the 13th as your last day in the office then it **is**.

Comment: Using the example from your link to the citizens advice page: 
"Your notice period starts the day after you resign. This means if you give a week’s notice on Monday your last day at work will be the next Monday."

Using the same logic, if my notice period is "one month" as stated in my contract and I handed in my notice on the 15th of November then wouldn't my last day be the same date on the next month i.e. the 15th of December? I think the ambiguity of how long "one month" actually is is what makes my last working day so hard to determine.

 Thanks for your advice, it's very helpful.

Comment: @Terry actually you're correct.. complete brainfart on my part this morning, will edit my answer appropriately

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you are mentally checked out from the company and moved on, which is even more reasons to have that discussion with your current boss. Explain that you just want to move on, asap, and ask how this can be facilitated. Usually, that means compiling a list of things that need to be delivered, and after that, the company can just let you go. In the end, the notice period is (almost) always negotiable when both parties agree.

And they will likely agree as you will not be performing at your best now, and keeping you on for longer than absolutely needed is not good for anyone, including the morale of other employees. So talk to your boss and agree together on a leaving plan, rather than arguing over Friday/monday as the last day.

Answer (score 3):

Check with your employer, but almost certainly Friday.